# New content type not showing in the List ribbon>New Item

Tags: content-type, ribbon, list-item

**I created a new content type (Gav).**

[image: content type screenshot]

**But only 3 content types are available via the ribbon**

[image: List Ribbon>New Item>only 3x content types are available]

Where is the 4th one?  Do I need to wait for the system to refresh perhaps?

- Of the 4 content types, one is made from the original list item content type.
- The other 3 content types were made at the site collection level, then added to the list.

Comment: do IIS reset...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In List Settings I could see all 4 content types (as you see in the 1st picture in the question).

- Via the ribbon>new item form>I chose `content type 1` (aka Charlie).
- I copied the url to this form and pasted in to Notepad.
- In this url I found the ContentTypeID - I will replace this with the ID from `Content Type 4`.
- To get the Content Type ID for the 4th content type: List Settings>content types>I clicked on `content type 4` (the one that does not show up via the Ribbon>New Item).  While viewing this content type I copied the url and pasted it in to Notepad.
- In Notepad I isolated the ContentTypeID from `content type 4`.
- I began with the new item form url for `Content Type 1`.  I substituted the unique Content Type ID.  This makes a new item form for `Content Type 4`.
- On the List page, default view - I added a `new item link` for `Content Type 4`.  I can now use all 4 content types.

Content Type 4 is still not showing up in the ribbon - but I have made manual links to all 4 content types instead.

[image]